# DynamoDB table name created with the serverless framework has a random suffix

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am using the serverless framework to create a DynamoDB table and then I want to access it from a Lambda function.

In the `serverless.yml` file I have the definitions below for the environment variable and CF resources.

What I was expecting was a table with the name `accounts-api-dev-accounts`, but what the cloudformation stack is creating for me is `accounts-api-dev-accounts-SOME_RANDOM_LETTERS_AND_NUMBERS_SUFFIX`.

In my lambda function the environment variable `DYNAMODB_ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME` is exposed to the function without the `SOME_RANDOM_LETTERS_AND_NUMBERS_SUFFIX` part. Is the CF stack supposed to add a random suffix? How do I actually retrieve the right table name?

```
service:
  name: accounts-api
provider:
...
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME: '${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-accounts'
```

And the following CF resource:

```
  Resources:
      AccountsTable:
          Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
          Properties:
            TableName: ${env:DYNAMODB_ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME}
            AttributeDefinitions:
              - AttributeName: customerNumber
                AttributeType: S
              - AttributeName: accountNumber
                AttributeType: S
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: customerNumber
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: accountNumber
                KeyType: RANGE
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Comment: Another comment, I get the following warning when deploying:  

Serverless Warning --------------------------------------
 
  A valid environment variable to satisfy the declaration 'env:DYNAMODB_ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME' could not be found.

Comment: maybe the environment variables are not updated yet at the time of the creation of the table definition? I'm not sure.
try `${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME}` instead of `${env:DYNAMODB_ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME}`

Comment: Bingo. Not sure why I can't use ${env} with it, but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the environment variables are not updated yet at the time of the creation of the table definition? I'm not sure.

Try `${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME}` instead of `${env:DYNAMODB_ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME}`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this behavior yet (random characters after deploy), it could be a way to force uniqueness when the table has to be replaced. You could use another environment variable and have the value populated by the Table resource's output. That way, CloudFormation will inject the actual resource name to the Lambda environment variable. I haven't tried this, but this would be my first "go to".

```
environment:
  DYNAMODB_ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME: '${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-accounts'
  ACTUAL_DYNAMODB_ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME:
    Ref: AccountsTable
```